Blazor Fluent UI AutoComplete not working
I'm trying to get the Fluent UI Autocomplete wired up to some demo data. I used the template creator to new up a project and I'm practically copying and pasting the example code and nothing is happening.
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>

<FluentAutocomplete TOption="Country"
                    AutoComplete="off"
                    Autofocus="true"
                    Label="Select a country"
                    Width="250px"
                    Placeholder="Select countries"
                    OnOptionsSearch="@OnSearchAsync"
                    OptionText="@(item => item.Name)"
                    @bind-SelectedOptions="@SelectedItems" />

<p>
    <b>Selected</b>: @(String.Join(" - ", SelectedItems.Select(i => i.Name)))
</p>

@code
{

  protected List<Country> Countries = new List<Country>
  {
    new Country {Name = "whatever", Code ="wh"}, 
    new Country {Name = "somewhere", Code = "so"}
  };

  IEnumerable<Country> SelectedItems = Array.Empty<Country>();

  private async Task OnSearchAsync(OptionsSearchEventArgs<Country> e)
  {
    e.Items = Countries.Where(i => i.Name.Contains(e.Text, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).ToArray();
  }

  public class Country
  {
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
  }
}

I've got the necessary configuration lines in Program.cs.
using Microsoft.FluentUI.AspNetCore.Components;
using FluentUIDemo.Components;
using FluentUIDemo.Services;
using FluentUIDemo;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
.AddInteractiveServerComponents();

builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

builder.Services.AddFluentUIComponents();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IMailService, MailService>();


var app = builder.Build();


I tested with your code but it works as expected, could you please make it more specific what nothing is happening means. I am starting the blazor web app, server render mode, global interactivity with .net 8 and my UI version is 4.6.0. You could provide more details so that we can troubleshoot, e.g. browser console.

Browser is Edge and .NET 8. I used the project template and ran the command "dotnet new fluentblazor -o {your project name}" to generate the project. Perhaps there's a bug with that? I made no settings changes. What is global interactivity?

I tested through directly creating a project in VS and the difference between project template and my approach is that render mode not applied in template project in Apps.razor.
You need to add the code in component to apply the render mode.
@page "/"

@rendermode InteractiveServer

<PageTitle>Home</PageTitle>
...


You can refer to the document to get more details. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0
